# Any Pros and Cons when leaving versions inside APIs?

Tags: java, versioning, release-management

Consider this, we have a set of APIs to be released and that are most likely to be re-designed from bottom up in the future, would leaving the versioning at package level for backward compatibility so that users can always get the latest release without worrying about breaking their codes better than to release different library versions where backward compatibility is not always guaranteed if users are not sticking to a certain released version?

e.g. MyClass-LATEST.jar, which has `package MyClass.v1;` and then in the future provide `package MyClass.v2;` while keeping `MyClass.v1` in the same library MyClass-LATEST.jar
as oppose to releasing MyClass-vX.X-RELEASE.jar...

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not put the version number in the API. If you release a version that is not backward compatible, the user does not need to upgrade. But if you make a release is backward compatible, such as a bug fix version, you will force the user to change their package names without just being able to drop in a new jar.

Build tools (ant, maven, gradle, etc) are used for managing versions. You shouldn't need to do so in your API package names.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I mean. Surely bug fixes will be there and stay within the same APIs. But v1, v2, ... would be different fundamentally. And of course, LATEST can also have bug fixes for pass old versions included.

Comment: But what if you have a v1.1 or v1.2? In either case, what benefit do you think putting the API version in the package name has?

Comment: Humm, numbering may confuse people. Let say its MyClass.lite; and later on MyClass.nextgen;... something like that

Comment: I wouldn't use qualifiers in your class names at all like that. It makes class names more confusing. If I want to use your API of MyClass, what a pain if I need to know if it's MyClass.lite, MyClass.nextgen, etc. It also makes development much more difficult, such as merging changes from MyClass.v1 to MyClass.v2, which are now different files. Keep it simple.

Comment: Right ok, so I get it people are trained to accept that v2.0-RELEASE may not be compatible with v1.0-RELEASE in that sense.

Comment: That is sometimes the case, but a good approach is to keep compatible when you can. Deprecate functionality across versions that will be removed. Try to avoid breaking when you can - but sometimes it's unavoidable.

Comment: And I guess the pros to have versions in APIs here is when you cannot guarantee backward compatibility. A new guy continues on someone else's project would not know it was implemented on v1.xxx-RELEASE and only works on those v1 major releases. And for us, we dont have to keep all the old versions on our hosting for the users to download a particular version.

Comment: You can have version numbers in your jars. Your build files will tell users what versions they are using.